# Facing an error on setFrom on sendgrid the wrd is not found in sendgrid

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

Unhandled sendgrid\mail\typexception. inspection infor: the exception reports which are neither enclosed in a try catch block nor documented using @thows tag

`$email->setFrom("noreply");`

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: I am trying to send and email and its not sending and when i hover over to the setFrom i see that error...Or if possible is there any other way i can send emails

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put an email to `setFrom`. Most websites use something like `noreply@sitename.com` or `no-reply@sitename.com`. But you're trying to use `noreply` which is not a well-formatted email address.

Here's more info about that [from SendGrid's itself](https://sendgrid.com/blog/why-you-should-not-use-noreplydomain-com-in-your-emails/).

Comment: i used this but still not workng```$email->setFrom("seh@gmail.com", "Example User");```